# Trying hard but can't hide featured post/page from grid

Tags: posts

i have a theme where first a featured post is displayed. then there is a grid of posts. Problem is grid also displays the featured post. So, featured post appears twice.

Question is **how to hide featured post from grid?**

Note that a custom meta box has been added to mark post/page as featured.

loop that starts featured section is as below...

```
if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post(); ?>
```

grid is formed from below code... (i need to hide featured post from this grid)

```
<?php
$counter = 1;

$grids = 3;

global $query_string;

query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=12&cat=-' . get_cat_ID( 'News' ));


if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the theme author's support?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook its not purchased theme. from static html to wordpress conversion.

Comment: Ah sorry. My misunderstanding.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook tried $featured in query post. not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp section of stackexchange really seems half dead.

you rarely get issue sorted.

have_posts checks whether there is any post, so add another condition that checks whether the post is featured or not.

```
if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post();
```

replace above with below

```
if(have_posts() && the_post() != $featured) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post();
```

Answer (score -1):

`caller_get_posts` is deprecated since version 3.1!

Use `ignore_sticky_posts` instead. [Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)

And don't use query_post it's not a good practice, [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: i think that is a suggestion for better coding and not an answer.